# MySQL update-and-get rows... or maybe select only unlocked rows?

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a complex query that eventually returns a Widget - the one that has been idle the longest. Easy.

Problem: I have a LOT of tasks who need to find the longest-idle Widget. (Keep in mind that the query for this is complex - it can't be reduced to a single queue of idle widgets.) There can be considerable contention for these Widgets - there may be a dozens of them that are classified as the longest-idle Widget, each for a different set of conditions. Nonetheless, a single Widget may have dozens of processes for whom a single Widget satisfies their constraints, all querying at the same time.

This is where the trouble sets in. I can run my complex query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT widgets.id FROM widgets INNER JOIN other_thing
ON .............
WHERE widgets.claimed = 0 ######## !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ##########
  AND other_thing.foobar = "yodeling monkey nuggets"
  AND ..........
ORDER BY last_active_time ASC
LIMIT 1
```

...which returns a widget to me, but I have to go BACK to the database to 
set claimed to 1. During this delay, many other processes will have

How can I set up this query so that it updates that one row, and ONLY that row, AND returns to me the ID of the claimed item?

Alternatively, I could switch over to a SELECT FOR UPDATE if there were a way to skip already-locked rows in a select, but I gather MySQL doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL version 8.0 or above,  yes there is "SKIP LOCKED".

Your query would look something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT widgets.id FROM widgets INNER JOIN other_thing
ON .............
WHERE widgets.claimed = 0 ######## !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ##########
  AND other_thing.foobar = "yodeling monkey nuggets"
  AND ..........
ORDER BY last_active_time ASC
LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE OF widgets SKIP LOCKED
```

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.